# What data structure is most suitable for implementing a 2-D array in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I want to implement a 2-D array kind of a thing.

What data structure will be most suitable for this? An array or some other data-structure will do. If there is any other data structure which will satisfy my requirement, then please tell me.

I don't want to use an array because the 2-D array needs to be declared early in the program but it is not fixed; the size will be determined at run time.

Also, the number of rows will be equal to the number of columns; this is fixed, because the same name will be given to both the rows and the columns.

I also want to traverse through this 2-D data structure as I would through a Map.

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what you really want to do... if the answers given aren't satisfactory, try improving the phrasing of your question and maybe adding some example code that shows how you would like to use your 2D data structure.

Comment: @Young: I've tried to rephrase your question. If I guessed your meaning wrongly, please edit it again.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want to use a row-key, a col-key, and then the value at that location.  There's no builtin data structure that'll do that for you.

The easiest thing to use may be a 2d array for the actual data.  Use something like the following to go from a row or column name to the actual index in your array.  Add as many name-to-index bindings as you want.

```
Map<String, Integer> rows = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<String, Integer> cols = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then getting that value in the grid...

```
grid[rows.get("Row name")][cols.get("Column name")];
```

Put the grid and a `get(String rowName, String colName)` method in a class if you want a cleaner API.

Edit: I see the question has been updated, and it looks like the name-to-index pairs are the same for both rows and columns.  So here's an updated version:

```
class SquareMap<V> {
    private V[][] grid;
    private Map<String, Integer> indexes;

    public SquareMap(int size) {
        grid = (V[][]) new Object[size][size];
        indexes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public void setIndex(String name, int index) {
        indexes.put(name, index);
    }

    public void set(String row, String col, V value) {
        grid[indexes.get(row)][indexes.get(col)] = value;
    }
    public V get(String row, String col) {
        return grid[indexes.get(row)][indexes.get(col)];
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea behind ur program looks more cleaner and efficient to use.. But i have not understo od the use of Grid..how do i use this grid in my program...

Comment: Hi, Please could you please explain me the functioning of this Grid... What is this grid and how can i store value in it...

Answer (score 1):

(Edits based on comment)

If the size is determined at runtime that is not an issue.  This might work:

```
final int[][]              data;
final int                  size;
final Map<String, Integer> names;

// code that sets the size variable
names = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
data  = new int[size][size];

names.put("ID-A", 0);
names.put("ID-B", 1);

data[names.get("ID-A")][names.get("ID-A")] = 39;
data[names.get("ID-A")][names.get("ID-B")] = 40;
data[names.get("ID-B")][names.get("ID-A")] = 41;
data[names.get("ID-B")][names.get("ID-B")] = 42;
```

Comment: Ok, i want to have it like this... I want that each row and column should have a name thru which it can mapped later on.. As there is a key in Map data structure in Java.util package... Is there any other way out...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays *can* be sized at runtime.  If you have a row/column size that doesn't vary too often, and the data is not too sparse, then an array is your best bet.

```
class TwoDimArray {
    public int[][] createArray(int nRows, int nCols) {
        return new int[nRows][nCols];
    }
    public int[][] resizeArray(int[][] oldArray, int nRows, int nCols) {
        int[][] newArray = new int[nRows][nCols];
        for (int i=0; i<Math.min(oldArray.length, nRows); ++i)
            for (int j=0; j<Math.min(oldArray[i].length, nCols); ++j)
                newArray[i][j] = oldArray[i][j];
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i want to have it like this... I want that each row and column should have a name thru which it can mapped later on.. As there is a key in Map data structure in Java.util package... Is there any other way out...

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a Map like

```
class TwoDArray<V> implements Iterable<Map.Entry<Point, V>> {
    private final Map<Point, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<Point, V>();
    public V set(int x, int y, V value) {
       return map.put(new Point(x,y), value);
    }
    public V get(int x, int y) {
       return map.get(new Point(x, y));
    }
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<Point, V>> iterator() {
       return map.entrySet().iterator();
    }
}

// to iterate
TwoDArray<Double> twoDArray = new TwoDArray();
twoDArray.set(3, 5, 56.0);
twoDArray.set(-1000, 5, 123.4);
twoDArray.set(789012345, -100000000, -156.9);
for(Map.Entry<Point, Double> entry: twoDArray) {
  //
}
```